# Get value of select option immediately jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I have a simple dropdown and want to get the specific value of an option if the user changes the dropdown selection, but without having him to push a submit button. Is this possible with jquery?

Here is what I got so far:

```
    <form action='select.htm'>
    <select id='BezirksAuswahl'>
    <option value='Alle'>Alle Eintr&auml;ge</option>
    <option value='Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf'>Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf</option>
    <option value='Reinickendorf'>Reinickendorf</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

and here the script:

```
$('#BezirksAuswahl').click(function(){
     $('#BezirksAuswahl option:selected').each(function(){
         alert($(this).val());
     });
 });
```

Thank you for your help and I am looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change` event, which fires when the value of the element changes, like so:

```
$('#BezirksAuswahl').change(function(e){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: thx for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work. none of the three examples here seem to fire the alert event. firebug shows no errors and the html is also valid.. any idea what the problem might be? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#BezirksAuswahl').change(function(){
         alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thx for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work. none of the three examples here seem to fire the alert event. firebug shows no errors and the html is also valid.. any idea what the problem might be? Thank you!

Comment: here is a jsfiddle page to show the code works.. http://jsfiddle.net/D99JW/ 
may be if you post your whole code, we might find a solution that might be preventing this from happening..

Answer (score 1):

its very simple.. try this

```
$('#BezirksAuswahl').change(function(){
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` is two unnecessary function calls, given that the `value` property of the element is readily available using `this.value`.

Comment: thx for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work. none of the three examples here seem to fire the alert event. firebug shows no errors and the html is also valid.. any idea what the problem might be? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check your JQuery include, you must not be including Jquery correctly. What version are you referencing?

Ensure you are running your script when JQuery is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#BezirksAuswahl').change(function(e){
     alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Run "$().jquery;" in console and tell us what you see

Comment: I'm running 1.7.1 and it's implemented correctly.. this question/problem is just a tiny part of a huge CMS project and all other js/jQuery related things work fine..

Comment: apparently it works if I include it directly in the source code of the html, if I put it in the external script, it doesn't..

Comment: Ah. I think you're not running your code at the right time. will update answer